# How many grandmas is enough grandmas?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I am currently over 450 million CpS and I now have access to the portals and time machines.

I have bought, over the course of this cookie clicker game, around 150 grandmas. Considering their upgrades and number, they have provided me with a lot of cookies since they were there from the beginning.

My question is : Considering that grandmas are now evaluated at 42 billions EACH, is it worth it to continue buying them with my spare cookies, or should I keep every cookies for bigger upgrades (like portals)?

P.S. This question could apply to farms and lower upgrades too.

Comment: The title alone makes me want to check this game out. +1

Comment: @tim you really got to try it :D

Comment: Damn you @KeineMaster, now I'm hooked. It's an OCD's dream... ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Grandmas have a bunch of upgrades that, like cursors, keep them somewhat relevant as you continue to progress. However, you should keep in mind that with the ever-increasing cost of things as you get more and more - it may not be efficient to sink hours worth of cookies into a purchase that does not increase your CPS by any meaningful amount.

Grandmas can be a little tricky as some of their upgrades increase the CPS of other buildings based on the number of Grandmas, but in general a basic formula to keep in mind is:

```
[Cost of new building] / [CPS per building]
```

Because I don't know the exact numbers you're working with, I'll use some numbers from my game as an example:

- Cursor: [Each: 1.151 billion/sec] [Next: 22.416 quadrillion]

  - = **19,475,239 cookies per 1cps**
- Grandma: [Each: 162.299 million/sec] [Next: 137.901 trillion ]

  - = **849,672 cookies per 1cps**
- Farm: [Each: 23,774.2 /sec] [Next 1.4 trillion]

  - = **58,887,365 cookies per 1cps**

While there are far more buildings to consider, out of those three - the cost per CPS is the lowest for a grandma. This is, however, a very basic formula that does not take into consideration other factors. For example, because of my cursor upgrades, each non-cursor object gives each cursor +55,555.6cps. As I have 250 cursors, this works out to roughly 13.9 million CPS per each non-cursor, so a farm would calculate out to **100,719 cookies per 1cps** which is a better deal than the grandmas.

It should be noted that while one building may be the most efficient *now*, every single purchase will alter the balance, so you'll have to re-calculate constantly. It can help to keep a spreadsheet.

---

Upgrades can be analyzed in a similar cost/benefit formula:

```
[Cost of upgrade] / [Expected CPS gain]
```

For example, my next cookie upgrade (pure black chocolate cookies) costs 50 quadrillion and would give +4% cps (4% of my current 5.5 trillion/sec works out to 220 billion per second). The efficiency of this upgrade is currently **227,273 cookies per 1cps**. That's more efficient than a grandma and less than a farm (if you consider the cursor upgrades)

---

Another factor that can influence your decision is time - although that cookie upgrade is rather efficient for me, it will take roughly 2.5 hours to reach 50 quadrillion cookies (not counting golden cookie bonuses), so if I'm actively paying attention to the game, I may opt to spend my cookies on a less efficient upgrade that I can purchase sooner because it's cheaper.

---

### TLDR;

You're going to need more of everything, and at 450million CPS, and grandmas starting at 42 billion, buying one will only set you back 1.5+ minutes worth of cookie generation. So even if it's not the most efficient choice currently, it won't set you back too far yet.

Comment: So, from my understanding of your post (awesome one btw), grandmas will be a setback only when I reach the point where the cost is too high for the amount of cookies given, which is not even yet the case for you in a more advanced game. I guess i'll continue to add more of tham grandmas to my evermaking cookie crew.

Comment: Side-note; I tend to structure my purchases so that each one is 10 more than the one below it, and then transition to 15 and 20 as the costs and my CPS allow, regardless of efficiency. MY OCD demands this.

Comment: Grandmas and Cursors are kinda unique in that their CPS is affected and effects most other buildings so their math is more complicated. But they should really just be treated as any other building. If there CPS gain to Cost is better then it's better.

Comment: I wish everyone could experience what it feels like to read an answer that nerds out so hard on a game about which I know absolutely nothing. Just realizing that CPS means "cookies per second" (I think) kinda made my day. That and the idea of buying grandmas for 42 billion cookies. "It can help to keep a spreadsheet" to **track your cookies and grandmas**!! I'm dying with laughter!

Comment: @ToddWilcox: the whole game is like that. You really ought to give it a try. Well, OK, you really shouldn't, because it's a black hole of a time sink, but it's a very amusing black hole of a time sink.

Comment: As mindless as Idle Games typically are, the math driving them is actually kind of interesting. While literally every decision only drives you forward there are a lot of things to consider for optimal play.

Answer (score 4):

No number is enough. If i tell you that 151 grandmas is enough, and you play the game for the next 2 years every single second. You'd end up with 10k of each, but the grandmas... So just keep buying and upgrading each of the buildings. I liked to keep mine to similar count, but just buy as much as you can all the time. And allays buy from the most expensive building first.

If you stop buying grandmas and concentrate on something else, eventually it would cost as much to buy one of that building, as it would to buy 10 grandmas.

I believe if you stall, your best endgame is to reset the game and get the bonus for resetting (forgot what it was called)... I play a different clicker on my Android, it'd take me a week to get to a CPS point, but if i reset it, the bonus would be so huge, it takes me an hour to get to that same point.
(EX: My first cookie ever, brought me 1 cookie, after few resets, now each of those cookies brings me 50 million cookies)